# Zoom cloud meeting for education

Tags: cheating, education, online-learning, audio-video-recording, video-conference

I have a paid (education) plan of Zoom cloud meeting. I use it for my university classes. I would like to get meeting participants’ names. How can I get that?

Comment: Click on the participants list while the meeting is in progress. You've tagged this `cheating` -- why?

Comment: @astronat 
-I need away to get a report of students names who are attend class all time of it. 
-because some students were registering on behalf of others.